# Nested For Loop Variable Increment

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, nested, increment

I've got a textbox displaying the sketch edited by the software, with variables being changed dynamically.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/398780553731506176/468835565304020995/unknown.png

But for the buttons array, I need to use some for loops to write the numbers

The format needs to be like this

`byte buttons[NUMROWS][NUMCOLS] = {
{0,1,2,3,4,},
{5,6,7,8,9,},
{10,11,12,13,14,},`

But all I can manage so far is

`byte buttons[NUMROWS][NUMCOLS] = {
{0,1,2,3,4,},
{1,2,3,4,5,},
{2,3,4,5,6,},`

I need to advance the loop so that the numbers increase. I'm using two nested for loops

```
        int i;
        for(int x = 0; x < rows; x++) //row
        {
            string buttonbyte = "{";
            for (i = x; i < columns + x; i++) //column
            {
                buttonbyte += i;
                buttonbyte += ",";
            }
            sketch[9 + x] = buttonbyte + "},";
        }
```

The code is for a program that edits an arduino .ide sketch and uploads it, for ease of use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Morgan

Comment: Can you use List<byte> instead of array?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's for the Keypad library. It requires the use of an two dimensional array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your second loop needs to be

```
for (i = (x * columns); i < ((x + 1) * columns); i++)
```

This will be 0,1,2,3,4  for the first iteration and 5,6,7,8,9 for the second and so on.

Comment: This implies lesser changes than my solution @MorGuux use this

Answer (score 0):

If the jump is always this you just need to make it so that

```
 int i;
        for(int x = 0; x < rows; x++) //row
        {
            string buttonbyte = "{";
            for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) //column
            {
                buttonbyte += (i + columns*x); // column + columns * row
                buttonbyte += ",";
            }
            sketch[9 + x] = buttonbyte + "},";
        }
```

PS: This might not work as i don't have a compiler now and you might need to convert (i + columns*x) to a string

Comment: Yeah that works, but it's one number too high.

The output is like 
{0,1,2,3,4,},
{6,7,8,9,10,},
{12,13,14,15,16,},

Comment: Make i start from zero everytime.

Comment: You would need to rewrite the second loop for this one to work to not include the X,    "for (i = 0; i < columns; i++)"  would work if you are building the number with (i + columns * x)

Comment: Yes i just noticed that... my bad. The problem of not having a compiler in hand